# React unread messages implementation

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have messages marked as unviewed when I enter the notification page. But after I left the page, all these messages should be marked as viewed. Where should I manage that?  I tried componentdidmount but it does not work

Comment: try ``` componentWillUnmount(). ```

Answer (score 1):

If it will be marked as viewed right after you leave the page and the components unmount, you should set the logic in componentWillUnmount(). Check documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)